# Variable that updates conditional value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns: Tick and Bid. This is tick data for a financial instrument. If the Tick column has a value price has moved up/down. The Bid column holds the current bid price. Here's an example:

```
Test <- data.frame(Tick=c(NA, NA, NA ,NA, NA , "1", NA, NA, NA,
                          NA, NA, "-1",NA, NA),
                   Bid=c("393.75", "393.75" ,"393.75" ,"394", "394",
                          NA,"394" ,"394","394","394","393.75",
                          NA, "393.75", "393.75"))
```

I want to create a variable I'll call `Best_Bid_Ex` that holds the value of the first price after a tick event occurs (`is.na(Test$Tick == FALSE)`) and resets with the new bid price with the next event.

```
Test$Best_Bid_Ex <- c("393.75", "393.75" ,"393.75" ,"393.75", 
"393.75", NA,"394" ,"394","394","394","394", NA, "393.75", "393.75")
```

I tried different indexing techniques but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 3):

In the devel version of 'data.table', there is a convenient function `rleid` for generating a `run-length_type_id` column for grouping purpose.

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Test)`).  Apply `rleid` on the logical index (`!is.na(Tick)`) to get numeric group for each set of 'TRUE/FALSE/TRUE' groups and then create the 'Best_Bid_Ex' as the first value of 'Bid' column (`Bid[1L]`) grouped by the numeric grouping from `rleid`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(Test)[, Best_Bid_Ex:= Bid[1L], rleid(!is.na(Tick))]
Test
#  Tick    Bid Best_Bid_Ex
# 1:   NA 393.75      393.75
# 2:   NA 393.75      393.75
# 3:   NA 393.75      393.75
# 4:   NA    394      393.75
# 5:   NA    394      393.75
# 6:    1     NA          NA
# 7:   NA    394         394
# 8:   NA    394         394
# 9:   NA    394         394
#10:   NA    394         394
#11:   NA 393.75         394
#12:   -1     NA          NA
#13:   NA 393.75      393.75
#14:   NA 393.75      393.75
```

Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Thanks. How did you install version 1.9.5?

Comment: install.packages("data.table", version='1.9.5')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  unused argument (version = "1.9.5")

Comment: @MichaelHenning  I updated the info about installing the package.